# Cannot add product in Prestashop back-office

Tags: javascript, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am new to Prestashop, and not an expert in code.

I'd like to add new products in my back-office but I can't, because the button "Record" loads  infinitely.

I opened the dev tools, and in the console, I get a 503 error.

There is also an error in `product.js` at line 177 :
`uncaught TypeError : cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`

I'm using Prestashop 1.6.1.5.
Can anyone help me ? Thanks.

Comment: You need to check which ajax call is resulting in a 503 error. Open the network console